# Error with Gatsby when trying to proxy request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, gatsby

I am getting an error when trying to proxy my dev url through Gatsby. In my gatsby-config.js I have:

```js
  proxy: [
    {
      prefix: '/myaccount',
      url: 'https://www-dev.site.com',
    },
  ],
```

[Gatsby Proxy Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3PZK.png)

`Error when trying to proxy request "/myaccount/" to "https://www-dev.site.com/myaccount/" write EPROTO 4584046080:error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 112`

`RequestError: write EPROTO 4555591168:error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 112`

This was working and all of a sudden stopped.

Comment: It looks like its a cert issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been said, it looks like a certificate issue (because of the SSL). Without more implementation details it's difficult to guess if a proposed solution will work on your scenario but you can try setting the security as false (`secure: false`) to don't reject self-signed certificates. In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware") 

module.exports = {
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/.netlify/functions/",
      createProxyMiddleware({
        target: "http://localhost:9000",
        secure: false, 
        pathRewrite: {
          "/.netlify/functions/": "",
        },
      })
    )
  },
```

*Docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/api-proxy/#self-signed-certificates*

Tweak it to adapt it to your needs, replacing `/.netlify/functions/` for your API endpoint.

Comment: I used this and it worked! Thanks!